# Solidity's address.transfer() function throwing exceeds gas limit error

Tags: solidity, remix

I am learning Solidity in order to make a simple user interface in which users can purchase items and have ether sent from the purchaser to the Store.

First, I have created one contract, one for the store and one for the purchaser.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ShoeStore {
    function () external payable {

    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return msg.sender.balance;
    }
}

contract StorePurchase {

    ShoeStore private _instance;

    function Store() public {
        _instance = new ShoeStore();
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return msg.sender.balance;
    }

    function sendEther() public payable {
        require(msg.sender.balance > 100);
        address(_instance).transfer(2);
    }

    function () external payable {

    }
```

First, I instantiate the ShoeStore contract within the StorePurchase contract so I can attain the address that the purchaser is to send to. Then, using the .transfer() function, I send 2 ether to the ShoeStore contract. However, I am getting an "Exceeds gas limit" error and I am unsure as to why I am exceeding the gas limit.

Perhaps, there is a design flaw in constructing the two contracts (I don't need to make security too much of a priority, I just need to make sure these transfer methods work). Or if someone can point me out to another resource that shows a simple way to transfer ether to one contract to another that would be helpful.

Comment: To begin with, change `require(msg.sender.balance > 100)` to `require(msg.value > 100)`, which is probably what you meant.

Comment: @goodvibration I do not think so. He is paying 2 ether, not spending more than 100... given this, cmonte, you are trying to transfer 2 Gwei there, not two ethers. This is non the problem you face, but it is a mistake. Today I’ll try to find time to read better your question...

Comment: @RickPark: Where exactly did I mention "Ether" anywhere in my comment? He verifies that **the caller** has a balance of 100, and then transfers 2 from **the contract**. So the caller could theoretically pass 0, and the contract will still transfer 2. This logic makes zero sense, which is what I tried to imply in the comment above.

Comment: You are right @goodvibration. This code cannot work flawlessly... there are many error or non logical sequences. For instance one can call the sendEther before to call the Store(), working then on an empty _instance; can call it without funds in the contract, as you stated perfectly, and so on.